# Simple multile-format ebook reader for macOS (no backup/sync, library management, etc.)

Tags: pdf, macos, ebooks, epub, mobi

I'm hunting for a *simple* ebook reader for PDF and eBup, and preferably Mobi too. On Linux I use mupdf, which has almost no features: it opens files when I run `mupdf the-file`, and has Vim-like keybinds (which is nice, but not a requirement). I've looked into getting it to work on Mac, but don't really want to mess with setting up X on Mac.

All the ebook readers I've found so far for Mac have lots of features that I don't want. I already have my library completely organized, I just want to be able to open files on the command line (or through ranger, which works out to the same thing). I don't want cloud sync, accounts, library management, or anything else. `open -a Preview.app` works for PDFs, but not the other formats.

I've also searched around on this stackexchange and didn't see any questions that looked right. Has anyone come across an ebook reader that sounds like this? It would also be nice if it can be installed with Homebrew, but if it has to be manually installed that's fine too (I don't have an Apple ID and don't want one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: mupdf-gl build from Homebrew doesn't work (it seems to be expecting X11, even though it's the OpenGL build), but grabbing the latest tarball from [the site](https://mupdf.com/downloads/) and installing from source (`make install`) works just fine!